# Attach Files To A User Record

Tags: administration, related-list, user, user-record, files

How would you go about allowing **attaching Files to a User record** (related list, preferably)?

This is a new request I never previously considered.  The only way I can think of is to create a simple custom object, and relate it to the User record, but so far, that seems unusable *(I've created the object, but cannot make it a Related List under User where I would want it)*.

The files would not be something publicly accessible, per se.  Could be HR records, time off requests, etc.  They would not be something the User themselves would see/touch normally (on their own User record), certain entities such as Human Resources would control/upload them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a custom object (for "Human Resources" purposes) which is linked to the User, and we attach files there as needed.   Think of "Person Accounts" (Account with Contact) or any "joined objects", essentially.